# OpenMapTiles docker doesn't start with previous configuration

Tags: docker, openmaptiles

I created a OpenMapTiles container:

- using a volume for `/data` directory
- using the image `klokantech/openmaptiles-server:1.6`.

The container started nicely. I downloaded the planet file. And the service was working fine.

As I am gonna push this to production: if the container dies, my orchestration system (Kubernetes) will restart it automatically and I want it to pick the previous configuration (so it doesn't need to download the planet file again or set any configuration).

So I killed my container and restart it using the same previous volume.

Problem: when my container was restarted, my restarted MapTiles didn't have the previous configuration and I got this error in the UI:

> OpenMapTiles Server is designed to work with data downloaded from OpenMapTiles.com, the following files are unknown and will not be used:
>   osm-2018-04-09-v3.8-planet.mbtiles

Also, I the logs, it appeared:

```
 /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/supervisor/options.py:298: UserWarning: Supervisord is running as root and it is searching for its configuration file in default locations (including its current working directory); you probably want to specify a "-c" argument specifying an absolute path to a configuration file for improved security.
  'Supervisord is running as root and it is searching '
2018-05-09 09:20:18,359 CRIT Supervisor running as root (no user in config file)
2018-05-09 09:20:18,359 INFO Included extra file "/etc/supervisor/conf.d/openmaptiles.conf" during parsing
2018-05-09 09:20:18,382 INFO Creating socket tcp://localhost:8081
2018-05-09 09:20:18,383 INFO Closing socket tcp://localhost:8081
2018-05-09 09:20:18,399 INFO RPC interface 'supervisor' initialized
2018-05-09 09:20:18,399 CRIT Server 'unix_http_server' running without any HTTP authentication checking
2018-05-09 09:20:18,399 INFO supervisord started with pid 1
2018-05-09 09:20:19,402 INFO spawned: 'wizard' with pid 11
2018-05-09 09:20:19,405 INFO spawned: 'xvfb' with pid 12
2018-05-09 09:20:20,407 INFO success: wizard entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 0 seconds (startsecs)
2018-05-09 09:20:20,407 INFO success: xvfb entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 0 seconds (startsecs)
Starting OpenMapTiles Map Server (action: run)
Existing configuration found in /data/config.json
Data file "undefined" not found!
Starting installation...
Installation wizard started at http://:::80/ 
List of available downloads ready.
```

And I guess maybe its this undefined in the config the one that is causing problems:

> Existing configuration found in /data/config.json
>   Data file "undefined" not found!

This is my config file:

```
 root@maptiles-0:/#  cat /data/config.json
 {
   "styles": {
     "standard": [
       "dark-matter",
       "klokantech-basic",
       "osm-bright",
       "positron"
     ],
     "custom": [],
     "lang": "",
     "langLatin": true,
     "langAlts": true
   },
   "settings": {
     "serve": {
       "vector": true,
       "raster": true,
       "services": true,
       "static": true
     },
     "raster": {
       "format": "PNG_256",
       "hidpi": 2,
       "maxsize": 2048
     },
     "server": {
       "title": "",
       "redirect": "",
       "domains": []
     },
     "memcache": {
       "size": 23.5,
       "servers": [
         "localhost:11211"
       ]
     }
   }
```

Should i mount a new volume somewhere else? should I change my `/data/config.json`? I have no idea how to make it ok for it to be killed

Comment: same issue here, I hope someone post an answer

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this using the image `klokantech/tileserver-gl:v2.3.1`. With this image, you can download the vector tiles in form of MBTiles file [OpenMapTiles Downloads](https://openmaptiles.com/downloads/planet/)

you can find the instructions here: https://openmaptiles.org/docs/host/tileserver-gl/

Also: I deployed it to kubernetes using the following StatefulSet:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1beta1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  labels:
    name: maptiles
  name: maptiles
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      name: maptiles
  serviceName: maptiles
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        name: maptiles
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: maptiles
        command: ["/bin/sh"]
        args:
        - -c
        - |
          echo "[INFO] Startingcontainer"; if [ $(DOWNLOAD_MBTILES) = "true" ]; then
            echo "[INFO] Download MBTILES_PLANET_URL";
            rm /data/*
            cd /data/
            wget -q -c $(MBTILES_PLANET_URL)
            echo "[INFO] Download finished";
          fi; echo "[INFO] Start app in /usr/src/app"; cd /usr/src/app && npm install --production && /usr/src/app/run.sh;
        env:
        - name: MBTILES_PLANET_URL
          value: 'https://openmaptiles.com/download/W...'
        - name: DOWNLOAD_MBTILES
          value: 'true'
        livenessProbe:
          failureThreshold: 120
          httpGet:
            path: /health
            port: 80
            scheme: HTTP
          initialDelaySeconds: 10
          periodSeconds: 30
          successThreshold: 1
          timeoutSeconds: 5
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
          name: http
          protocol: TCP
        readinessProbe:
          failureThreshold: 120
          httpGet:
            path: /health
            port: 80
            scheme: HTTP
          initialDelaySeconds: 10
          periodSeconds: 30
          successThreshold: 1
          timeoutSeconds: 5
        resources:
          limits:
            cpu: 500m
            memory: 4Gi
          requests:
            cpu: 100m
            memory: 2Gi
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /data
          name: maptiles
  volumeClaimTemplates:
  - metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      name: maptiles
    spec:
      accessModes:
      - ReadWriteOnce
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 60Gi
      storageClassName: standard
```

I first deploy it with `DOWNLOAD_MBTILES='true'` and after I change it to `DOWNLOAD_MBTILES='false'` (so it doesnt clean up the map next time it is deployed).

I tested it and when it has `DOWNLOAD_MBTILES='false'`, you can kill the containers and they start again in a minute or so.